# C# constructor and type where a object is constructed

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

Is there a way to allow a constructor to know where or within what type at the instance f construction, the object is being constructed within? For exampel, if you view the following code, could the type be placed somewhere with reflection inside of the logger class, to tell where the instance was created? Instead of hard coded the information.

```
public class MyCollection 
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Entities : MyCollection");
}
```

Instead, doing something to where I could just call

```
LogManager.GetLogger();
```

And within log Logmanager, I would know during the constructor what type it was initialized within? That way it could be generically used, and on every class instance.

Comment: Does it only need the type name? What are you going to do with the type within the constructor? After construction, what is logger doing differently based on type that created it?

Comment: NLog's `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` does exactly that (are you using NLog? :P), check its [source code (defined in the LogManager.GetClassFullName() method)](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/LogManager.cs#L379), it's using Reflection to get name of the caller.

Comment: You should use System.Reflection

Comment: What's the purpose of knowing what's creating the object?

Comment: I was hoping to use reflection against it. So I could get things like type name, namespace, etc.

Comment: Do you have control over the LogManager? If yes, then, just change the GetLogger method to accept System.Type instead of System.String. Thus, the created logger instance may be told which type created it.

Answer (score 3):

You could define the Logger constructor to have a parameter (Object obj) and create it by new Logger(this).

Then you can use GetType().Name to determine the type of the object.

Comment: Great idea, and I though about that. Was wondering if there was some deeply hidden property I didn't know about, but that is a good way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another option to avoid hard coding names like this but to also avoid using reflection is to use the new C# 6 `nameof(MyCollection)` syntax which will give you the name `"MyCollection"` in a way that will survive renaming.

It's not exactly what you were asking for but it is a clean, refactoring-safe, efficient way to pass the name to a static logger like this.

Comment: Nice, and thanks. Didn't know about "nameof". Though I was wanting more control over the object then just name of the type.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two options:

- Use `Environment.StackTrace`. That'll give you the complete call stack (unless it's optimized away I suppose).
- Pass `this` to the method:

For the latter, you can create an extension method:

```
 public static class MyLogger
 {
    public static void Log(this object o, string format, params object[] par) 
    {
        string typeName = o.GetType().Name;
        string msg = string.Format(format, par);
        // Pass to logger
    }
 }
```

use like this:

```
 this.Log("foo {0}", 12);
```

**Note:**

There are already a lot of good .NET loggers available. I'd rather use one of those than make one of my own, because at some point you'll run into concurrency issues and stuff like that.

Comment: Yea, we are suing log4net currently. I was just wondering, and completely overlooked the obvious log(this), then using reflection to get what I needed. Thanks everyone.